# Weird VB .Net interaction with Oracle.DataAccess error

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, oracle, .net-assembly

When I access Oracle.DataAccess from my frontend .ASPX pages, I am having no problems on either my local development box. But when I try to access them from my backend .VB class file, I am getting the "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)" error.

I don't think this is a x86 versus x64 problem, as I am building in x86 and the test server I am trying to deploy to is 32 bit.

I have enabled Fusion Logging and have Gotten the following:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
LOG: DisplayName = Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/Kconnect/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Kconnect\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Kconnect\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: \\?\c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/kconnect/e206d030/c1f3aafc/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/kconnect/e206d030/c1f3aafc/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/Kconnect/bin/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: So what version is installed on your server? Check the GAC.

Comment: I have a copy of the exact DLL from the server on my local dev machine.

Comment: And what about the dependencies?

Comment: The weird thing is that both the files (bin folder of server and bin folder of dev) are showing up as version 2.111.7.20. The version in my oracle install folder is 2.112.1.0.

I am guessing I need to uninstall that and find the right version for the 2.111.7.20 ?

Comment: Enable [fusion log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) and see what it says.

Comment: What version of the Oracle Client have you installed?

Comment: I am having my server administrator turn on Fusion Logging right now.

Comment: I have a suspicion that 11gR1 is installed on the test server and I have 11gR2 installed on my dev box.

Could this cause an issue? I can't find 11gR1 to install it.

Comment: The thing that is getting me is that I can successfully load it from the ASPX page, but not from a backend VB page.

Comment: Did you try using the managed ODP.NET? It's much much better than the old one.

Comment: How do I go about using the managed ODP.Net?